# Use SBT 1.3.x with Scala 2.13.8

Tags: scala, sbt

After upgrading the Scala version to `2.13.8` (from `2.13.3`) of my Scala project, the following error gets at load time:

```
[error] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'sbt.internal.util.Init$Initialize sbt.Def$.ifS(sbt.internal.util.Init$Initialize, sbt.internal.util.Init$Initialize, sbt.internal.util.Init$Initialize)'
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

Upgrading to SBT `1.4.x` fixes this issue. But I can't upgrade to SBT to `1.4.x` and want to use SBT `1.3.13`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: May I ask, just by curiosity why can't you upgrade **sbt**?

Comment: Because of this error: https://github.com/playframework/play-ebean/issues/214

Comment: Oh right, why I am not surprised that a simple binary compatible update breaks **play**, really I don't understand why people keep using that. Anyways, sorry not not being of help.